# Ignoring a function from make

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to implement a Command Line Interface for an existing project. The way I am doing this is using two separate makefiles. One is the makefile already existing for the project, the other is for the CLI. I run the CLI makefile first, getting the necessary files and then link these files with the existing project using the makefile of project. Now, the problem is every time I add functions from existing project to the CLI file, the CLI makefile goes ahead and builds these functions, which I dont want it to do, since thats not necessary and gives me warnings and errors (since I dont want to keep including all headers and .o's).

To cut the long story short, can I do something so that the makefile of CLI ignores the function added to CLI file and not look inside the function to check for everything?

Comment: If the CLI doesn't depend on the files you're changing, don't add those files as dependencies in the CLI Makefile. If it _does_ depend on them, surely it needs to rebuild?

Comment: The CLI does depend on them, in the sense that it parses through the function name, but it doesnt really need to rebuild, since its more interested in the name of the function (the actual string) rather than whats going on inside the function. Besides I will be adding this CLI file in the main project, where it can check the function all it wants to!

Comment: If the CLI depends on the header that declares the function(s), but not on the `.c`, it'll recompile only when functions are added/removed/renamed and not on changes to implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let one of the makefiles add a definition for a macro (calling it useCLI) in the compilation process (`-DuseCLI`). For the functions you don't want to compile, surround them with `#ifndef useCLI` and `#endif`. Beware of dependencies, though.

Comment: Excellent! That might actually help!